# Is there a way to make Google Docs work on desktop?

Tags: google-docs

I want to ditch my Microsoft Office and use Google Docs, but I would like Google Docs to be available on the desktop, not through a browser.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Google Docs use HTML, JavaScript, and CSS to do their "magic". They need a browser to work. Any app that would work as a standalone app will simply be a wrapper around a browser canvas.

If you want to ditch Microsoft Office, your best option is probably [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/) and/or [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/).